# Including both Age and Year in mixed effects model?

Tags: time-series, mixed-model, panel-data, multicollinearity, age

**Study**

Longitudinal study of forest `GrowthRates` across time.

- 28 plots across 80 years, ~14 samples for each plot.

Current model:

```r
lmer(GrowthRate ~ I(Year-1970) * factor(PlotType) + 
         (1 + I(Year-1970)|Plot), data = dat)
```

**Purpose**

Determine the annual change in my response variable, `GrowthRate`.

- In other words, **has GrowthRate increased through time?**

**Problem**

I need to account for other variables by adding them to my model. Specifically, my plots vary in `age`, which likely plays a significant affect on the trend I see.

- Older plots are theoretically going to have different growth rates vs younger plots.

As a result, I **need to account for the effects of age** to focus in an actual *temporal* trend.

**Question**

**Given that `Year` and `Age` are almost certainly strongly colinear, how could I incorporate `Age` into my model?**

- Thoughts: perhaps I could add an "initial age" variable to try to capture this effect? Would this work, or would this simply be repeating effects captured by my Plot ID structuring?
- What's the best (or any appropriate) way to go about isolating the actual annual trend (i.e., the estimate for `Year`) from trend effects due to plot `age`?

Comment: Basically, is there any way to do this and it be valid???

Comment: You may get some inspiration from reading about "Age-Period-Cohort analysis"